# И сразу же — аналогичное: "всучить"

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Пока писал предыдущий вопрос, понял, что слово "всучить" тоже совершенно неясно. Оно-то откуда взялось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Современное значение ("обманом заставить взять что-то, продать негодную вещь") возникло переосмыслением исконного значения: "вплести методом сучения" (от глагола сучить – "свивать в одну нить несколько прядей").

Словарь Крылова.

Т.е. *всучить* - это буквально приплести, навязать что-либо.

Answer (score 1):

Значение[править]
суча, вплести ◆ Для этого значения не указан пример употребления. Вы можете оказать помощь проекту, добавив пример употребления из литературного произведения или повседневного общения.
разг. заставить взять, купить и т. п. обманом или хитростью; навязать ◆ Для этого значения не указан пример употребления. Вы можете оказать помощь проекту, добавив пример употребления из литературного произведения или повседневного общения.
Синонимы[править]
вплести
навязать (п.), впарить (жарг.). Нашел в интернете.И вот еще: http://books.google.az/books?id=lVjlAAAAMAAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA329&img=1&pgis=1&dq=%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%92%D0%9F%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%AC&sig=ACfU3U2r4FQIrGMAnG8QHloH3dQfGnwQ2A&edge=0

Answer (score -1):

Вручить -  от него  всучить ( с оттенком собачьей пренебрежительности к действию )